# String assignment confusion

Tags: c++

I have the following code.

```
string s1,s2;
cin>>s1;
s2[0] = s1[0];
cout<<s2.length()<<endl;
```

The output of `s2.length()` is zero.

When I print

```
cout<<s2<<endl;
```

The output of `string s2` is an empty string.

But for

```
cout<<s2[0]<<endl;
```

It's print a character.

My question is why is `string s2` empty ?

Comment: Undefined behavior is difficult to predict.

Comment: You are trying to store something in s2 where no storage has been allocated. What would you expect if you did `s2[1000000] = s1[0];` ?  It's the same rhing with position `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [operator[i]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) assumes that `0<=i<size()`. If `i==size()` the behavior is undefined, unless you set `s1[0]=std::string::value_type()`. See the provided link for further details.

To have some runtime error also note that you can use `at()` instead of `op[]`:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s1;
  s1.at(0) = 'A';
}
```

gives a runtime error:

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
> /bin/bash: line 1: 28559 Aborted                 ./main
> ```

Answer (score 1):

"Picaud Vincent" responsed correctly.

The operator[] was builted for accessing index of string or writing to specified index of pre-allocated memory of string. you can't increase size of the string with operator[] .

If you want to Add some chars to end of string you should use operators like **+=** or use **push_back()** method.

For clarify, += operator or push_back() do these steps sequentially :

1- Check string memory size if there isn't enough space for adding new chars 
,they extend string memory

2 - Copy new chars at the end of current string

3 - Increment string length,

But operator[] only set the value of specified index and nothing more, and if you set invalid index, you may receive access violation exception and for sum up  **operator[] doesn't extend string memory or change string length**.